# Find the indices of the center point of a data cube using xarray

Tags: python-xarray

I'm trying to extract a 3D cube from a data array using `xarray` in Python but first I need to extract the 3D indices of the center point. I've tried using the code below but I am getting all 0 indices which I know is incorrect.

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

arr3d = np.random.randint(-100, 100, size=(5, 5, 5))
lev = np.array([0,1,2,3,4])
lat = np.array([-1,0,2,3,4])
lon = np.array([-175,-174, -172, -171, -170])
da = xr.DataArray(
    data=arr3d,

    dims=["lev", "lat", "lon"],
    coords=dict(
        lev=(["lev"], lev),
        lat=(["lat"], lat),
        lon=(["lon"], lon) ),
)
# desired point in space
clat = 2 
clon = -175
alt = 4
# assuming the min will be just 1 value
indices = da.where(((da==lev) & (da==clat) & (da==clon)), drop=True).squeeze()
print(indices.values)
```

The output: [], an empty list

I do not get an error so the syntax is correct but I suspect that this is not the right way to extract the center point. I'm also looking for a way, if I can get the indices of the center point, how to extract a cube that is 1 cell away from this point.

Comment: can you clarify exactly what isn't working the way you expect? we can't run your code as-is, so either a [mre] with dummy data produced from code or a very clear explanation of what you're getting and what you expect would be helpful.

Comment: It's also really hard to tell where the problem is because there's so much going on in the code, and so much of it is specific to your workflow. is the problem something to do with altitudes or pressure levels or lat/lon/clat/clon/glat/glon??? Check out this guide to [crafting a minimal bug report](https://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports) - it's a really helpful guide to both debugging and asking questions most likely to get help.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Apologies for the ill-posed question. Please see the above improvements. Just trying to get a point in a 3D array at this point. Next step is to extract a 3D cube.

Comment: thanks so much for the work to improve this - this example is great!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you’re running into is that you are comparing your array values to the desired coordinates. Instead, filter by masking the coordinates themselves:

```py
indices = da.where(
    ((da.lev==alt) & (da.lat==clat) & (da.lon==clon)),
    drop=True,
).squeeze()
```

The result of each of these masks is a 1-D DataArray, but they will be broadcast against each other when combined with `&` due to xarray’s [broadcasting rules](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/v2022.03.0/user-guide/computation.html#broadcasting-by-dimension-name).

Note that while the above works, it’s more efficient and straightforward to select the data directly using [`da.sel`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.sel.html):

```py
indices = da.sel(
   lev=alt,
   lat=clat,
   lon=clon,
)
```

You can select a subset cube using either syntax. Doing this with where could be done using inequalities or checking membership in a list using each coordinates [`.isin`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.isin.html) method. With `.sel`, you could provide the list explicitly, use inequalities to provide a Boolean mask and slice with [`.isel`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.isel.html), or provide ranges inside a `slice()` object, just to name a few.

Since you're asking specifically about finding a cube with a specific *positional* distance away from the center point, this can get a bit tricky, as you need to identify the positional location of the center. You can do this currently by accessing each dimension's index object in the `.indexes` attribute, and making use of their [`.get_loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) methods to find the location of each value:

```py
In [63]: lat_loc = da.indexes['lat'].get_loc(clat)
    ...: lon_loc = da.indexes['lon'].get_loc(clon)
    ...: alt_loc = da.indexes['lev'].get_loc(alt)

In [64]: lat_loc, lon_loc, alt_loc
Out[64]: (2, 0, 4)
```

This can then be used to select up to one position above and below each location, but respecting the boundaries `[0, len(dim)-1]`:

```py
In [65]: da.isel(
    ...:    lev=range(max(0, alt_loc - 1), min(len(da.lev), alt_loc + 2)),
    ...:    lat=range(max(0, lat_loc - 1), min(len(da.lat), lat_loc + 2)),
    ...:    lon=range(max(0, lon_loc - 1), min(len(da.lon), lon_loc + 2)),
    ...: )
Out[65]:
<xarray.DataArray (lev: 2, lat: 3, lon: 2)>
array([[[ 51, -42],
        [  1, -19],
        [ 26,  26]],

       [[-46, -78],
        [ 65,  73],
        [-34, -33]]])
Coordinates:
  * lev      (lev) int64 3 4
  * lat      (lat) int64 0 2 3
  * lon      (lon) int64 -175 -174
```

See the guide to [indexing and selecting data](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/v2022.03.0/user-guide/indexing.html) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. I'm testing it out and it seems to be doing what I need. Only I keep getting this warning:
`FutureWarning: Passing method to Float64Index.get_loc is deprecated and will raise in a future version. Use index.get_indexer([item], method=...) instead.`

Comment: Are you passing the keyword argument method? That wasn’t in my answer. Happy to help debug but I’d need to see your code. Also feel free to ask another question if it’s sufficiently different from this one.

Comment: No problem with your code. It's this warning that I get it in one environment and not locally. The source: 'profile39 = fh.dist.sel(lat=[clat], lon=[clon], method='nearest')'.
If you think I should put this in another question, I would happy to do it.
I'm new to `xarray` and it's the syntax that is so difficult to understand. I don't understand the python data structure, i.e., methods, class, dictionaries and how they are chained together. For example, in your answer: `indexes` is a method that works like a dictionary and the class has another method `get_loc` that can be chained together.

Comment: I think I've found the source of the warning but I am none the wiser for it:
`profile39 = fh.dist.sel(lat=clat, lon=clon, method='nearest')` causes the warning but this one doesn't: `profile39 = fh.dist.sel(lat=[clat], lon=[clon], method='nearest')`

Comment: oh - I wouldn't worry about that warning. That's a futurewarning being raised by pandas which xarray will need to change to accommodate. DataArray.sel will remain a supported part of the xarray API.

Comment: here's a relevant issue: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/6625. I think upgrading xarray will remove the warning

Comment: as for the chained syntax - yep definitely something to learn! DataArrays are pretty complex objects and learning how to use it effectively does involve learning the APIs of some of the internals too. like Datasets, `DataArray.indexes` implements the *Mapping* protocol, meaning you can access each index with dict-like access, e.g. `da.indexes['lon']`. The indexes you're accessing are also objects of type [`pd.Index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.html) (or similar), which have their own methods and attributes. And so on... :)